# django rest framework - Save extended user data to db

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try implement registration endpoint for user with additional attributes like phone_number and full_name.

I implement the logic for saving user data, which come from request, but I can't understand how I can save profile data, like phone_number and full_name.

I have a user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(_('is verified by admin'), default=False)

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.username:
            self.set_username()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """Send an email to this user."""
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)

    def set_username(self):
        pass
```

And profile model:

```
class Profile(TimeStampedModel):
    STATUS = Choices(
        ("inactive", _("inactive")),
        ("active", _("active")),
        ("banned", _("banned"))
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        verbose_name=_('related user'),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='profile',
        related_query_name='profile'
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        _("description of user's profile"),
        blank=True,
        default=''
    )
    status = StatusField(
        _("status of the user")
    )
    birth_date = models.DateField(
        _("Date of birth"),
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(
                datetime.date(1910, 1, 1)
            ),
            MaxValueValidator(
                datetime.date.today
            )
        ],
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    avatar = models.OneToOneField(
        "files.Avatar",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="profile"
    )

    full_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        default='',
        blank=False
    )
    phone_number_regex_validator = RegexValidator(regex=COMPILED_REGEXP)

    phone_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=16,
        default='',
        blank=False,
        validators=[phone_number_regex_validator]
    )
    objects = ProfileQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"profile of user {self.user_id}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('profile')
        verbose_name_plural = _('profiles')
```

Here is my serealizer for users:

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):  # pylint: disable=abstract-method

    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True, help_text=_('Email address')
    )
    password1 = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True, help_text=_('Password')
    )
    password2 = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True, help_text=_('Password Confirmation')
    )
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True, help_text=_('Phone number')
    )
    full_name = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True, help_text=_('Full name')
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cleaned_data = {}

    @staticmethod
    def validate_email(email):
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        if email and email_address_exists(email):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_(
                "A user is already registered with this e-mail address.")
            )
        return email

    @staticmethod
    def validate_password1(password):
        return get_adapter().clean_password(password)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password1'] != attrs['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_(
                "The two password fields didn't match.")
            )
        return attrs

    def custom_signup(self, request, user):
        pass

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'phone_number': self.validated_data.get('phone_number', ''),
            'full_name': self.validated_data.get('full_name', '')

        }

    def save(self, request):  # pylint: disable=arguments-differ
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        self.custom_signup(request, user)
        setup_user_email(request, user, [])
        return user
```

And signals where profile object created and save to db:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

How i can save all neded attrs for model profile in the db?

Comment: Is it not an option to create the profile in the serializer's `save()` right after you create the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just set up the customer profile in the `save` method, rather than using a signal here.
In here you can add the `@transaction.atomic` decorator to the view, so it ensure either `both rows are created` or `neither rows are created`.

If you really want to use the signal, you would need to write your own one that sends the entire `validated_data` over.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/#defining-and-sending-signals

On a side note,

1. The `get_cleaned_data` method looks a bit weird to me since all fields in the Serializers are required, you can just use `self.validated_data` in the `save` method.
2. your `validate_<field>` method should just be instance methods rather than class methods, according to the DRF doc, you can ignore your linter here.

See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation

Answer (score 1):

This is something related which I did, this is not the exact answer but closely related. I was adding a USER-GROUP, BRANCH to a user at the time of registration. Check the SUPER keyword in Views.py.

I extended the user model so that I can get all information about the user in one place.

This is my model.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class User(AbstractUser):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank = True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True)
    dob = models.DateField(null = True,blank = True)
    mobileNumber =  models.CharField(max_length=15,blank = True)
    maritalStatus = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank = True)
    localAddLine1 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(branch,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 
        'user_brn_data', blank = True, null=True)
    user_group = models.ForeignKey(user_group,on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name = 'user_group_data', blank = True, null=True)
```

This is my serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
#        fields = ("__all__")
        exclude = ['password']
```

And this is my View.js

```
from rest_auth.registration.views import RegisterView
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
class CuustomRegisterView(RegisterView):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        data = request.data
        branch = data['branchId']
        groups = data['userGroupId']
        email = data['email']
        isSuperUser = data['isSuperUser']
        User.objects.filter(email=email).update(branch=branch, 
        is_superuser=isSuperUser, user_group=groups, branch =branch)
        return response
```

You can use the SUPER keyword of python to call the main function and extend the role of it to achieve what you are looking for.